# How to determine if swift firebase node updated

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am observing to see if a node in firebase was updated so that I can reload the data in a table. I have this code observing the node, but I can't find anything specific on how to check if a nodes values have changed.

**Observing the "info" node in firebase:**

```
for activeGrp in FriendSystem.system.activeGroups {
    FriendSystem.system.CURRENT_USER_GROUP_REF
        .child(activeGrp.groupID)
        .child("info")
        .observe(.value, with: { 
            (snapshot) in
                //This is where I am lost/////////////////
         })
    }
```

**Array of Groups**

```
var activeGroups = [Groups]()

func addActiveGroupObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
    CURRENT_USER_GROUP_REF.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.activeGroups.removeAll()
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let id = child.key
            self.getGroup(id, completion: { (group) in
                self.activeGroups.append(group)
                self.activeGroups.sort {$0.name < $1.name}
                update()

            })

        }
        if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
            update()
        }
    })
}
```

**Firebase Node**
[image]

Comment: ovserving is used to notify if node is updated so no need of additional code. You set observer so whenever your node is updated tour method will automatically called.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I know what i need to do now, just was under the impression you needed to identify a specific change

Comment: if you want to observe only change event then you can set CURRENT_USER_GROUP_REF.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in

Answer (score 0):

you have to use FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged

Listen for changes to the items in a list. This event is triggered any time a child node is modified. This includes any modifications to descendants of the child node. The snapshot passed to the event listener contains the updated data for the child.

for detailed description use the following URL.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data